# Unable to understand this stack trace(parse.com)

Tags: android, apache, parse-platform, crash, crashlytics

I am using crashylytics in my application. Its been about 2 months into production. I have had a few crashes which I have been able to resolve but these last few days I am getting a stack trace which is not pointing me to a line in my code (or even an activity) at which point the crash occurred.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:120)
       at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.eofDetected(BasicManagedEntity.java:161)
       at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkEOF(EofSensorInputStream.java:239)
       at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:179)
       at com.parse.ParseIOUtils.copyLarge(ParseIOUtils.java:129)
       at com.parse.ParseIOUtils.copyLarge(ParseIOUtils.java:106)
       at com.parse.ParseIOUtils.copy(ParseIOUtils.java:81)
       at com.parse.ParseIOUtils.toByteArray(ParseIOUtils.java:55)
       at com.parse.ParseRESTObjectBatchCommand.onResponse(ParseRESTObjectBatchCommand.java:66)
       at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:229)
       at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:225)
       at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
       at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:482)
       at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:358)
       at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:369)
       at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:415)
       at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:407)
       at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And this.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer.<init>(ByteArrayBuffer.java:53)
       at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.init(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:82)
       at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:70)
       at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
       at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:172)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:587)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
       at com.parse.ParseApacheHttpClient.execute(ParseApacheHttpClient.java:97)
       at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:228)
       at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:225)
       at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
       at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:482)
       at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:358)
       at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:369)
       at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:415)
       at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:407)
       at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Typically in crashes I find a line

`at com.justmedit.datatrix.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:90)`

Which points me to the line causing the crash.
Could someone please give me advice as to why this is happening or the possibilities so I can investigate this and fix it in the next release. Thanks!

Added code I am using for scaling bitmaps -

```
public Bitmap ScaleImage( String value, float dimension){
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(value);
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        float scale;
        if (width>height){scale=dimension/width;}
        else {scale=dimension/height;}
        ExifInterface exif;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(value);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);}

        }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

This lets me pass the location of the image on the sd card and a float number which determines the dimension of the largest size once the image is rescaled.

Comment: I tend to believe this question is more or less the same issue you're facing ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411710/fatal-exception-outofmemoryerror .

Comment: I also believed the crash may be due to uploading multiple bitmaps using Parse. If I need to upload 6-7 bitmaps, each of size 200kb, save them as Parse Files and make a pointer from them to the original object, what would be an effective way of doing it? Writing the code in the onClick itself is causing the UI to freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Bitmap in Sample size. look at [Loading bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

```
 public static int calculateInSampleSize(

      BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
       // Raw height and width of image
       final int height = options.outHeight;
       final int width = options.outWidth;
       int inSampleSize = 1;

       if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
         inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height
           / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
         inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
       }

       return inSampleSize;
      }
```

Following method will decode `Bitmap` in sample size from `Byte` array.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromBytes(byte[] bytes, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

       Bitmap bm = null;
       // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
       final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);

       // Calculate inSampleSize
       options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
         reqHeight);

       // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
       bm =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);

       return bm;
      }

      public static int calculateInSampleSize(

      BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
       // Raw height and width of image
       final int height = options.outHeight;
       final int width = options.outWidth;
       int inSampleSize = 1;

       if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
         inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height
           / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
         inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
       }

       return inSampleSize;
      }
```

100 is a height and width, you can modify according to your need.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromBytes(bytes, 100, 100);
```

Hope it will help.!

Comment: I have seen this code and had used it with some changes. I have added the new code. please do help me out. Thanks